# php and mysql procedure that runs once per month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php built website with a mysql database.

I need an sql function to run once per every month.

How would i go about doing this?

**EDIT**

Really sorry for not making it clear. I don't have a linux VPS. Just a basic hosting service with php and mysql capabilities. I am looking into purchasing a "real" server in the future but for now, are there any onther methods?

Comment: http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/

Comment: MySQL event scheduler would be a good option if it is available to you - check out Johan's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone seems to want you to use a cronjob.
Problem with that is that is requires superuser access to the server.
I would suggest using a MySQL event instead.

Note that this does require superuser access in the MySQL database.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

First make sure the event scheduler is enabled:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

You can set up an event as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_name ON SCHEDULE EVERY MONTH
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE 
COMMENT 'comment'
DO BEGIN
  //SQL statements here.
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Nice answer - particularly if OP does not have access to set up CRON jobs. The only thing I would add is to ensure that the event scheduler is enabled: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I've been hunting for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have proper access to the server, I would set a [CRON](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) job.

Most of the modern distribution have a folder `/etc/cron.monthly`, you can put your script there and it will be run each month.

If you want more control when the script is ran, you can setup your own CRON entry.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a cronjob that points to a PHP file containing a call to your SQL query.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

you could use cronjobs to fix this :).

greets,
stefan

Answer (score 1):

CRON JOB is the solution for this. Tuts [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/).